# Customizing print output after getting a column using 'cut' command

Tags: unix, cut, xargs

I'm trying to print the first column of output in a "customized" way, after executing a program that prints out a table. I know how to get the first column from the output, but I want to print each row between single quotes. So, right now I have the commands that can get me the first column:

```
./genTable | cut -f2 | xargs -0
```

What can I add to this command so that it prints the values between quotes. For example, the output right now looks like

```
apple
cider
vinegar
```

I want it to look like

```
'apple'
'cider'
'vinegar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `awk` ;-) , i.e.

```
    ./genTable | awk -v singleQ="'" '{print singleQ $1 singleQ}'
```

And of course you if you want super-minimalist, change all references from `singleQ` to `Q` ;-)

**output**

```
'apple'
'cider'
'vinegar'
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Perl. `./genTable | perl -nwla -e 'print \'$F[1]\''`